# Draw 2D curves with Desmos?

Tags: desmos

I'm trying to get more familiar with desmos.com for visualizing functions and formulas.
It's great to plot regular functions like y(x)=....

Is there also a way to plot parametric curves in the 2-dimensional plane?

For example:

```
x = sin(t)+2*sin(2*t)
y = cos(t)-2*cos(2*t)
```

or

```
( sin(t)+2*sin(2*t) , cos(t)-2*cos(2*t) )
```

And then I'd expect something like

[image]

Is there a way to do this in Desmos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by pasting your second version, it assumes that t is a parameter, which has a defaut range [0,1]. By extending the range appropriately, you can achieve your desired figure.

[image: robphy-desmos]

Comment: Thanks! I would swear I did try that. Maybe this feature wasn't there yet at the time? Just tried again now and it works wonders! 